# Putting arguments of function automatically

Tags: functions, function-construction

This is a snippet of a code that I have:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
ReArrangedTable[{x_, YReal1_, YImag1_, YReal2_, YImag2_}] := {x,
  YReal1, YImag1, FunctionValue[YReal1, x],
  YReal2, YImag2, FunctionValue[YReal2, x]}
MappedTable = Map[ReArrangedTable, SolutionInTableForm]
```

Here, `SolutionInTableForm` consist of numerical values with dimensions which depends on the input- lets say that for this case its {1000,5}. This 5 values is taken into
`x_,YReal1_,YImag1_,YReal2_,YImag2_`. And, `FunctionValue` is a sample function that I define earlier and then I use `Map`. This seems to be fair enough.

But, when value of 5 changes to 7 or 9 or 13, then I am forced to type arguments of `ReArrangedTable` manually and also RHS of `ReArrangedTable`. Is there any way to "automate" this?

Edit 1:

Ideally I am expecting to have a code like this:

```
ValueOfY = 20
ReArrangedTable[{x_, YReal1_, YImag1_, YReal2_, YImag2_, ...., 
   YReal19_, YImag19_, YReal20_, YImag20_}] := {x,
  YReal1, YImag1, FunctionValue[YReal1, x],
  YReal2, YImag2, FunctionValue[YReal2, x], ... .. YReal19, YImag19, 
  FunctionValue[YReal19, x],
  YReal20, YImag20, FunctionValue[YReal20, x]}
MappedTable = Map[ReArrangedTable, SolutionInTableForm]
```

Is this possible to do this automatically?

I am using Mathematica 11.0.0.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you have the input with a length of 12?  From the structure you give, would then length always be odd?

Comment: Sorry, you are correct and that was mistake. I have updated that.

Answer (score 1):

Does the following do what you want?

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
ReArrangedTable[xy_] := 
  Join[{xy[[1]]}, Flatten[Table[{xy[[i]], xy[[i + 1]], 
  FunctionValue[xy[[i]], xy[[1]]]}, {i, 2, Length[xy], 2}]]]

SolutionInTableForm = {{x, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 7},
  {x, 2, 3, 5, 1, 3, 9},
  {x, 4, 5, 2, 9, 1, 1}};

MappedTable = Map[ReArrangedTable, SolutionInTableForm]
(* {{x, 1, 2, FunctionValue[1, x], 1, 3, FunctionValue[1, x], 2, 7, FunctionValue[2, x]}, 
    {x, 2, 3, FunctionValue[2, x], 5, 1, FunctionValue[5, x], 3, 9, FunctionValue[3, x]}, 
    {x, 4, 5, FunctionValue[4, x], 2, 9, FunctionValue[2, x], 1, 1, FunctionValue[1, x]}} *)
```

Comment: While executing your code with `ReArrangedTable[{x, YReal1, YImag2, 1, 3}]`, I am getting o/p `{x, YReal1, YImag2, FunctionValue[YReal1, x], 1, 3, FunctionValue[1, x]}`. This give only LHS and that too I am supposed to write YReal and YImag in `ReArrangedTable[{x, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 7}]`, which is tedious. Further how about RHS?

Comment: I'm not understanding what you mean about "RHS".  I just added in the part with the `Map` function.